# Two cross-date data listing errors with the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin

I just want to get date, and when I say convert, it makes a mistake.

```
 public List<viBill> GetAll(viBill viBill, int startPage, int endPage, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string keyCode, string userName, string password, string code)
    {
        var viUser = new viUser() { UserName = userName, Password = password, Code = code };
        if (_viUserService.ControlKeyCode(viUser, keyCode))
        {
            var result = viBillDal.GetAll(x => x.Deleted == false && x.BusinessID == viBill.BusinessID && Convert.ToDateTime(x.Date).Date >= startDate.Date && Convert.ToDateTime(x.Date).Date <= endDate.Date && x.IsItDebt == viBill.IsItDebt).ToList();
            return result.ToList
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It's a message of error and this {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: Two possibilities 1) The object is already a DateTime and doesn't need to be converted 2) The string format of the date is not a standard date string so you need to use DateTime.ParseExact() instead.

Comment: Break the line into two lines . First get the data  without applying date filter and then apply where for date columns

Comment: What is the type of startDatein viBillDal ?

Comment: "it makes a mistake" is not a very helpful description

Comment: try *DateTime.Parse(x.Date) >=startDate.Date && DateTime.Parse(x.Date)<= endDate.Date*

Comment: as @Jason Said..... Add the exception message as well

Comment: What value do you have before and after Convert?

Comment: It's a message of error and this  {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: @SmtHm what is the type of viBillDal.Date (x.Date) ?

Comment: Why are you using "Convert"? is it s string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumming that viBillDal or viBill is a List the correct way is just to select with LINQ:

```
var result = viBillDal.Select(c => c.startDate >= startDate && c.endDate <= endDate);
```

if viBill is a context

```
public async Task program()
    {
        using (var context = new viBill())
        {
            //do your work
            GetAll(context, .......);
        }
    }

    public static IQueryable<viBill> getGlobalAll(this viBill dbContext, int? startPage = 0.....)
    {
        var query = dbContext.Blogs.AsQueryable();

        if (startPage.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(c => c.startDate >= startDate && c.endDate <= endDate);
        return (IQueryable<viBill>)query;
    }

    public List<viBill> GetAll(this viBill context, int startPage, ......)
    {
        var viUser = new viUser() { UserName = userName, Password = password, Code = code };
        if (_viUserService.ControlKeyCode(viUser, keyCode))
        {
            var result = getGlobalAll(context);
            return result.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Hope you find useful.